# Why does converting a certain short to double equal a 4004 digit number?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, double, short

When I run the following program a 4004 digit number is printed:

```
double d;
short s;
d = 23234564568788.5;
d = s = d;
printf("%lf\n", d);
```

Why?

Comment: Overflowing a signed integer while converting is UB. It'll do who-knows-what. https://ideone.com/K4diK7

Comment: Types on the dupe I linked are different, but the answer is the same.

Comment: This is not overflow, this is just case of the value not be representable. However the behaviour is still undefined. So you might as well get `23234564568788.5` or a floating point exception... or `Hello world`

Answer (score 1):

This is UB. On my machine, for example, the result is `-32768.0`.

My gcc outputs this warning:  `warning: conversion to 'short int' from 'double' may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]` meaning you shouldn't do this as it is not the way C should be written (if one expects code to run properly).